# Python Multiprocessing in Google Cloud Run kills container unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, python-multiprocessing, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to use multiprocessing in Python on a Cloud Run container but Cloud Run just exits unexpectedly with the error.

```
Uncaught signal: 11, pid=1, tid=13, fault_addr=69102686133216.

Container terminated on signal 11.
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'm running some calculations that take a while to run from a class instance.
Everything runs fine locally.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

class ExampleClass:
  # ...
  
  @staticmethod
  def some_calc(a,b,c):
      # ...

  def some_method():
      # The below pool uses the maximum number of processes available to work
      iterable_arguments = [] # will have tuples of 3 items
      with Pool() as pool:
          result = pool.starmap(self.some_calc, iterable_arguments, chunksize=5)
     

class AnotherClass:
  # ...

  def MyGRPCMethod(self, request, context, **kwargs):
      routing = threading.Thread(target=self.example_class.some_method)
      routine.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Serves a gRPC server
   # ExampleClass.some_method is called from AnotherClass.MyGRPCMethod method that runs 
   # in a separate thread.
```

Please note that `some_method` is being run in a separate thread from the main one using the threading package.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any clues?

**Cloud Run Specs**

- Concurrency: 80
- CPU limit: 2
- Memory limit: 4GiB

**Python**
Version: 3.11

Comment: How long take your processing? Is your container killed after 15 minutes?

Comment: The tasks shouldn't take more that 15 mins. The problem is that the multiprocessing doesn't even run. As soon as it gets to the multiprocessing block the container exits with that error.

Comment: Please note that `some_method` is being run in a separate thread from the main one using the threading package.

Comment: Having similar issues with cloud run and starmap. I'm sending concurrent requests to another cloud run service and I can see the requests hitting the other service, but for some reason the service running the starmap gets killed and never returns the results. Curiously using map did work. Did you manage to work around this?

Comment: @antti No, I never figured it out, we just got rid of multiprocessing completely

Comment: Same, we actually went with httpx and asyncio instead of multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run is designed to handle user requests and scale up/down based on that. The **CPU by default is allocated only during the request processing, and lost as soon as your response returns**.

You can enable **short living** always-on CPU... https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation but keep in mind that the container can anyway scale to 0.

Quick guide about processing in background: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#background-activity

Also, if you only need to run some background processing, have a look to Cloud Run Jobs. A new feature born to handle such use cases. It has different running behaviors and less running constrains.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. We're already using always allocated CPUs and have been running background tasks up to the 15 mins limit. We've been using this via Go's goroutines and Python's threading.

Comment: Did you try the min instance option? The always on option not throttle the CPU outside the request processing window, but continue to kill the instance after 15 minutes